# Export C# Solution to PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, export-to-pdf

I have to generate my whole Project as a PDF-File (every class has to be included).

The only was I found was to Print every Class as one PDF with the Visual Studio built-in Print function.

Is there an easier Solution?

**I don't want to do this I have to do this s**t**

Comment: I doubt there is, as a solution simply consists of so many different files, not just C#-files. However it shouldn't be that hard to loop through every C#-file in your projects and print them

Comment: What. The. Funk?? Did you step on someone's toes or are you dealing with a Dinosaur?

Comment: @Fildor I don't want to do it I have to do it

Comment: I wonder who on earth will ever read through thousands of PDFs. I agree Fildor, that seems a pretty pointless job unless you want some retro-feeling within your office.

Comment: That's kind of like printing out emails ... *smh

Comment: OP did not mention anything about the size.

I can imagine this request in some situation (like auditing, or , more likely, school/academic project). For some archiving reasons, that could make some sense (from a bureaucrat point of view).

Comment: Why specifically do you need to do this? Assuming the goal is traceability, it should be sufficient to save the full git revision id, possibly in combination with a full backup of the repository. In my experience, requirements like this are sometimes caused by someone interpreting some regulation, and that interpretation has become an immutable requirement, even if the actual regulation may be met by other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this bash command from the top directory:
(works even on Windows if you have WSL installed)

(case sensitive)

```sh
cat `find . -type f -name '*.cs'` >> concat.txt
```

Or Windows powershell equivalent (not case-sensitive):

```
get-childItem . -Recurse -Filter *.cs | get-content | set-content concat.txt
```

Then you'll have all your files as one `concat.txt`, and you can print it with your favorite editor.

If you need to automate this process, there are command line pdf generator, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.